# How to construct NSPredicate with multiple complex conditions

Tags: ios, nspredicate

Consider a `CustomObject` class that has the following properties:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *source;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray<CustomObject2> *linkedItems;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *parentId;
```

How would I construct an `NSPredicate` to handle the following scenario:

1. All `CustomObject` objects with `source` value of `1` and non-empty/non nil `linkedItems` array.
2. All `CustomObject` objects with `source` value of `2` and `parentId` equal to `item1`.
3. All other `CustomObjects` with `source` values other than `1` or `2`

For example:

```
Custom Object 1
source = 1
linkedItems = Custom Object2 1, CustomObject2 2
parentId = nil

Custom Object 2
source = 1
linkedItems = nil
parentId = nil

Custom Object 3
source = 2
linkedItems = nil
parentId = item1

Custom Object 4
source = 2
linkedItems = nil
parentId = item2

Custom Object 5
source = 3
linkedItems = Custom Object2 3
parentId = nil
```

After using the predicate I would like to have Objects 1, 2, and 5.

I'm stumped on an elegant solution for this... any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Look up the documentation for `NSCompoundPredicate`, which has class methods that can construct predicates for `AND`, `OR`, and `NOT` conditions using other predicates as input.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //All CustomObject objects with source value of 1 and non-empty/non nil linkedItemsarray.
    let predicateA = NSPredicate(format: "(source == 1) AND (linkedItems != nil) AND (linkedItems.isEmpty == false)")


    //All CustomObject objects with source value of 2 and parentId equal to item1.
    let predicateB = NSPredicate(format: "(source == 2) AND (parentId != %@"), item1)


    //All other CustomObjects with source values other than 1 or 2
    let predicateC = NSPredicate(format: "(source != 1) AND (source != 2)")

    let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .AndPredicateType, subpredicates: [predicateA,predicateB,predicateC]) 

    let filtered = yourArray.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just filter by the first predicate? Where do predicateB and predicateC come into play?

Comment: yes, in the code above I am only filtering by one predicate to filter by multiple predicates use NSCompoundPredicate(type: .AndPredicateType, subpredicates: [predicateA, predicateB, predicateC])

Comment: @Zach I updated the answer to better reflect the question.